# Make NAA a red-flag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, not-an-answer

I think NAA should be a red flag such as spam or rude so non answers get removed in a shorter time frame.

What this means:

- Each time a post is flagged as NAA, the [Community ♦︎](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1) user downvotes it.
- After three flags, the post disappears from the front page.
- After six flags, the post is:

  - locked
  - deleted
  - author loses 100 rep

This would help discourage answers like this:
[image: not answer]

or this:
[image: also not answer]

Can we make NAA a red flag?

Comment: If a post is *not* an answer and is causing harm by being on the site, then you can flag it as "rude or abusive". A post being mildly annoying doesn't really harm anybody.

Comment: NAA are often posted by new user who might simply not know better. Instead of punishing them with a red flag and risking them getting banned by the system, give them a chance to learn from the mistake!

Comment: This change would be really harmful. There are so many "why was my flag declined" questions here on MSO where users don't understand when to use an NAA flag, that it would cause more harm than it will help. Those valid, but maybe bad answers would still get flagged incorrectly and "punished" for invalid reasons.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Agreed. Punishment does not work (for example, it is far too late). That is why it is very important that the software is designed to dispel [any expectation of a forum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPbbt7Dg-2U&t=2m57s) that many users have (not to speak of Stack Overflow employee onboarding).

Comment: Reminds me of the History and Moral Philosophy in Starship troopers. *If you wanted to teach a baby a lesson, would you cut its head off?*

Comment: Both examples you gave were cases of misunderstanding the site. That requires course correction, not punishment.

Comment: Until it's a demonstrated pattern. Then it rates denial of service for those who can't be bothered to make the effort to understand. This is unfortunately seen as punishment. It is also already what the system. I don't have a good solution for folks who prove unable, as opposed to unwilling, to understand the site.

Comment: "After three flags, the post disappears from the front page"—Answers don't show up on the front page, questions do. This proposal appears to punish the question because someone (might have) posted a bogus answer to it. Or were you just suggesting this for cases where the only reason the question is (back) on the front page is due to that question being posted? (E.g., someone saying "Was there any answer to this?" a year later.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this is excessive. NAAs are not harmful to the site, at least not in the way spam or rude/abusive content is harmful. There's no need to rush the deletion of NAAs, they get deleted soon enough.

Your point about discouraging NAAs is valid, but there are already mechanisms in place for this. A user who posts enough answers that get downvoted and deleted will get answer-banned before long. There's no need for them to be given the standard red-flag penalty, which is quite harsh.

Comment: No need to -100 for each NAA. You're right.